# Angular 7 Http get request function exits?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-httpclient

I have a function in my Angular project which makes a get request to a REST backend and does something with the data. Nothing special. This is in authservice.ts.

This method is called from the interceptor. However, before the request is completed, the interceptor calls handleAuthError() because the method returned false (how??) while the request hasn't been made. I can see this because nothing happened in the backend. Then the application does make the request and can handle the data.

Has anybody experienced this issue or could suggest how I could fix this?

```
// api.interceptor.ts

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      return next.handle(request).pipe(tap(data => {
      return data;
    },
    error => {
      // if (request.url.indexOf('/refresh') !== -1) {
        // Already attempted to refresh the token. Log out
        // this.authService.handleAuthError();
      // } else {
        // If the token can't be refreshed then log out.
        if (!this.authService.refreshJwt(this.tokenService.get())) {
          this.authService.handleAuthError();
        }
      // }
    }));


// auth.service.ts

refreshJwt(token: string): boolean {
  if (token == null || token.length <= 0) { return false; }

  const requestUrl = this.apiUrl + '/refresh';

  const requestOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: `Bearer ` + this.tokenService.get()
    }),
  };

  this.http.get(requestUrl, requestOptions).subscribe(
    data => {
      // return true;
      return this.handleJwtResponse(data);
    }, error => {
      return false;
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: `I can see this because nothing happened in the backend` <= The request could be failing for a different reason entirely and might not be getting to the server to begin with. Double check your browser's network activity tab in the developer tools.

Comment: I checked in the network tab. There are two request sent to the /refresh endpoint and they both get a 200 response. Only the second request has a response body though.

The first response has no body at all..